# Count votes of a survey by the answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a survey relative to income. I have my data like this:

```
   form  Survey1  Survey2  Country
0     1        1        1        1
1     2        1        2        5
2     3        2        2        4
3     4        2        1        1
4     5        2        2        4
```

I want to group by the answer and by the Country. For example, let's think the Survey2 refers to the number of cars of the respondent, I want to know the number of people that owns one car in a certain country.

The expected output is as follows:

```
   Country  Survey1_1  Survey1_2  Survey2_1  Survey2_2
0        1          1          1          2          0
1        4          0          2          0          2
2        5          1          0          0          1
```

Here I added '_#' where # is the answer to count.

Until now I've created a code to find the different answers for each column and I've counted the answers responding, let's say 1, but I haven't founded the way to count the answers for a specific country.

```
   number_unic = df.head().iloc[:,j+ci].nunique() # count unique                                          answers
    val_unic = list(df.iloc[:,column].unique()) # unique answers
    for i in range(len(vals_unic)):
        names = str(df.columns[j+ci]+'_' + str(vals[i])) #names of columns
        count = (df.iloc[:,j+ci]==vals[i]).sum() #here I                                        count the values that are equal to an unique answer        
        df.insert(len(df.columns.values),names, count) # to insert new columns
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
In [11]: df.pivot_table(["Survey1", "Survey2"], ["Country"], df.groupby("Country").cumcount())
Out[11]:
        Survey1      Survey2
              0    1       0    1
Country
1           1.0  2.0     1.0  1.0
4           2.0  2.0     2.0  2.0
5           1.0  NaN     2.0  NaN
```

---

To get the output you wanted you could do something like:

```
In [21]: res = df.pivot_table(["Survey1", "Survey2"], ["Country"], df.groupby("Country").cumcount())

In [22]: res.columns = [s + "_" + str(n + 1) for s, n in res.columns.values]

In [23]: res
Out[23]:
         Survey1_1  Survey1_2  Survey2_1  Survey2_2
Country
1              1.0        2.0        1.0        1.0
4              2.0        2.0        2.0        2.0
5              1.0        NaN        2.0        NaN
```

But, generally it's better to use the MultiIndex here...

---

To count the number of each responses you can do this somewhat more complicated groupby and value_count:

```
In [31]: df1 = df.set_index("Country")[["Survey1", "Survey2"]]  # more columns work fine here

In [32]: df1.unstack().groupby(level=[0, 1]).value_counts().unstack(level=0, fill_value=0).unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[32]:
        Survey1    Survey2
              1  2       1  2
Country
1             1  1       2  0
4             0  2       0  2
5             1  0       0  1
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried your post but I'am getting too many columns (18872 to be precise). I'm not sure what the code is doing.

Comment: @JuanDanielBustillosCamargo it's hard to say why that would be without seeing the data. From your example this groups the surveys and and person from that country number. To see what the code is doing, you can run `df.groupby("Country").cumcount()` perhaps that better explains how it enumerates people from each country.

Comment: why did you use ' df.groupby("Country").cumcount()' for the columns parameter? I understand what it does but in the columns I want the answers e.g. Survey2_2

Comment: @JuanDanielBustillosCamargo see the second half of the answer.

Comment: I'm obtaining +18,000 columns and I can't figure out the meaning of the dataframe obtained. For example, I have a column called Survey1_11 with nonzero entries for certain countries, while the only valid answers are [0,1,2,3,4]. How can I show you my data?

Comment: @JuanDanielBustillosCamargo you mean because that particular country only has 5 entries? This result will have the maximum number as columns i.e. if one country has 11 surveys it will have that number of columns.

Comment: Each country has several entries (10000+) but all entries has 5 possible answers [0,1,2,3,4]. That's why I don't understand why I have a columns called Survey1_XXX with non zero entries while the expected result would be only [Survey1_1,Survey1_2,Survey1_3,Survey1_4,Survey1_5] and not [Survey1_1,Survey1_2,...,Survey1_ 18872]

Comment: @Juan I see, the issue, will put up fix.

Comment: Maybe I didn't formulated my question correctly: the subscript '_XX' refers to the answer, for example, Survey1_1 refers to the people that answered '1' for the Survey1. As you can see on the part of the expected output of the question, I counted the number of people that voted 1 for the survey1, in the case of country 4 the expected output is 0 because no one answered 0 for that survey.  Hope that you can help me.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I understand the question, going to have to think about this a little more!

Comment: @JuanDanielBustillosCamargo added as [31]

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about creating a for: ' for index, row in df.iterrows():       if df.iloc[index,'Survey1'] == df.iloc[1,'Survey1'] & df.iloc[index,'COUNTRY'] == df.iloc[1,'COUNTRY]: count +=1 ' It won't run but you get the idea. I don't want to implement it because it will take years to run.